# Magento 2: Issues with mobile navigation when moving navigation.sections with layout xml

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I'm attempting to move `navigation.sections` into `sidebar.main` on a three column Magento 2 layout.

I have a custom theme inheriting `Magento/blank`. I have moved the navigation using:

**MyVendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="navigation.sections" destination="sidebar.main" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This renders as expected on desktop, and also on mobile.

However, when activating the menu on any category page, the grey overlay `.nav-open .nav-toggle:after` sits above the navigation. CSS z-index for the navigation/overlay seems to go out of the window.

[image]

This only occurs on category pages. On CMS and product pages the menu works as expected.

How would I go about diagnosing this further from here?

Answer (score 0):

above the navigation CSS z-index is comming from **.nav-toggle**.

```
.nav-toggle{
   z-index: inherit;
}
```

Like:

```
.catalog-category-view .nav-toggle{
   z-index: inherit;
}
```

make sure you have to add parent class before this class. another then it will effect on other pages.